# Creating Multisample Texture Correctly

Tags: opengl, textures

For standard OpenGL textures, the filtering state is part of the texture, and must be defined when the texture is created.  This leads to code like:

```
glGenTextures(1,&_texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,_texture_id);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(...);
```

This works perfectly.  I am trying to make a multisampled texture (for use in a FBO).  The code is very similar:

```
glGenTextures(1,&_texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,_texture_id);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2DMultisample(...);
```

I am using a debug context, and with this code the first `glTexParameterf(...)` call causes:

> GL_INVALID_ENUM error generated. multisample texture targets doesn't support sampler state

I don't know what this is supposed to mean.  Notice that multisampled textures only support nearest filtering.  I am specifying this.  I noticed that for some of the calls (in particular `glTexParameterf(...)`), the `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE` is not a listed input in the documentation (which would indeed explain the invalid enum error if they're actually invalid, not just forgotten).  However, if it is not accepted, then how am I supposed to set nearest filtering?

Comment: I haven't used multisample textures, but my understanding is that because only nearest filtering is supported, you don't need to set it. Does your code work without the calls to `glTexParameterf`?

Comment: It does.  If you can find a source, post as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to set nearest filtering because multisample textures are not filtered at all. The [specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.core.20120806.pdf) (section 8.10) does list `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE` as a valid target for `glTexParameteri` (which you should use instead of `glTexParameterf` for integer parameters), but lists among possible errors:

> An INVALID_ENUM error is generated if target is either TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE
>   or TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE_ARRAY, and pname is any sampler
>   state from table 23.18.